# SQL Server : remove character "

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to remove from my value / string this character `"` but I can not remove it using my `UPDATE` statement here:

```
UPDATE dbo].[Tablename] 
SET [columnname] = REPLACE([columnname], '"', '')
```

Do you have any idea how to remove this character?

Thank you for opinions

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Other than missing a [ in front of dbo, this should work

Comment: `REPLACE([columnname], U&'\0022', '')`?

Comment: Have you got this working ?  If so , would be good to hear what the issue was;  if not, where are you struggling ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the ASCII character codes to replace the wildcard characters. There might be other good solution as well. It worked for me!

`UPDATE dbo].[Tablename] SET [columnname] = REPLACE([columnname], char(47), '')`

Char(47) is the ASCII code for the forward slash. You can find the full list [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/).

Comment: Its gone true but not change when i call back select * from tablename

Comment: Are you comitting the update? Are you selecting from different databases with cloned results? (updating 1 environment selecting from another?)

Comment: saw you edited your question, you actually want to remove " from column value. I tried in my sql-server 2014 with select REPLACE('hello"', '"', ''). It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

So first make 100% sure of the character you are trying to eliminate.
Just because it 'looks' like a double quote, doesn't mean that it is.

Alter the commented line in the code below, to select a single record from your dataset.
It will spit out the charcode for each character in the source string.
(obv change table and field names also !)

```
declare 
    @sample nvarchar(max),
    @char nvarchar(1),
    @i_idx int,
    @temp int

    create table #RtnValue(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    A  nvarchar(max),
    [uni] int,
    [ascii] int 
    ) 

   -- set @sample to a single value from your dataset here
   select @sample = (select  top (1) [sample] from test.test)


While len(@sample) > 0
Begin
    Set @char = left(@sample,1)
        Insert Into #RtnValue (A, uni, [ascii])
        Select A = @char, UNI = UNICODE(@char), [ASCII] = ASCII(@char)  
    Set @sample = RIGHT(@sample,len(@sample)-1)
End

Select * from #RtnValue
```

Comment: I'm just suggesting you find a single record that contains the target character. Do the character code analysis just on that one string.  I say because there are different variations of a double quote, and depending on font and screen - they can look alike.

Comment: For example     select CHAR(34)   select CHAR(147)